# Frame by Frame on Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, android-animation, live-wallpaper, duration

Is there a way to draw frame by frame animation on the Bitmap for live wallpaper?
I have the follow code, and the frames do show up on the live wallpaper.
However, they all show up at the same time instead of one by one.
It seems like there is no duration in between the frames somehow.

Could someone help please?
Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
        int frame = 0; 
        for (;frame < 8; frame ++)
        {

            int[] pirates_frame = {
            R.drawable.frame1, R.drawable.frame2, R.drawable.frame3,
            R.drawable.frame4, R.drawable.frame5, R.drawable.frame6,
            R.drawable.frame7, R.drawable.frame8,};


            icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),pirates_frame[frame]);
            canvas.drawBitmap(icon, x2, y2, null);
            System.out.println("frame is : " + frame);
            icon.recycle();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no time delay in there. It is just going to loop right away until it is done. You should try using a runnable or thread with a delay to draw each frame.

There is a nice tutorial that uses runnables here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html

Also I recommend against initializing your pirates_frame in the for loop, as you are doing the same thing 8 times and in some cases that could really slow things down.